# Not able to read data from Mongodb for below schema

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Am trying to read very complex `json` from mongoDB. Tried in multiple ways nut no luck. `Sample schema below :`

```
root
     |-- _id: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- oid: string (nullable = true)
     |-- customerInfo: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- events: array (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- relevantField: integer (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- relevantField_2: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- situation: array (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- currentRank: integer (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- info: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- customerId: integer (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Would a Python based answer work for you? Or you want an answer specific to PySpark?

Comment: Please check if this link is helpful: https://survival8.blogspot.com/2022/09/creating-dummy-database-and-collection.html